# Combination: In n chooses r $\binom{n}{r}$, what if $r$ is larger than $n$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, binomial-coefficients

I want to choose $r$ items from $n$ items while the order of selection is not important. Using combination definition, there are $\binom{n}{r}$ different ways I can do that. What if $r>n$? I expect the answer should be $0$ but all programming functions I have been testing returns error. I was wondering from a mathematical point of view, $0$ is a correct answer?

Comment: That's it. Thanks

Comment: R does not give an error: `choose(1,2)` gives `0` while `choose(1.5,2)` gives `0.375` as you might expect from my answer in the linked question